# what tool can I use to convert GoToMeeting video to Flash video?

Tags: windows, video, gotomeeting

I have a GoToMeeting video that has been recorded in GoToMeeting's proprietary format. I'd like to convert it to Flash. Is there a free or inexpensive tool that I can use to do this?

It's about an hour of video, so re-recording is a last resort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try this again.

Search for and download Expression Encoder 3 from Microsoft,they have a free version which will let you edit the recording and save as a vanilla WMV file without the GoToMeeting codec. If you do not have GoToMeeting installed on your PC you will need to install the codec from http://www.gotomeeting.com/codec  From here you can use AnyVideoConverter or another application called Freemake to convert the WMV into another format including Flash.

My previous answer was not intended to advertise my blog, I do not make any money from it, I simply work for Citrix and and I am trying to provide answers to questions our customers are asking.

Thanks,

Comment: Maybe it'll be helpful (and you won't get downvotes) if I post your blog? Detailed post about gotomeeting recording:  http://glenndcitrix.wordpress.com/2010/12/17/the-ultimate-gotomeeting-recording-guide/

Answer (score 1):

Install Citrix GoToMeeting. Go to folder with GoToMeeting and find file g2mtranscoder.exe. Run in command shell in this folder

g2mtranscoder source=*Full Path\File Name.wmv*

for example:

g2mtranscoder source=c:\records\record1.wmv

This tool help covert GTM format in Windows Media.

Answer (score 0):

I have a couple of guides on my blog that you can follow to remove the codec and then convert the vanilla WMV file into Flash or another format.

http://glenndcitrix.wordpress.com/2010/12/17/the-ultimate-gotomeeting-recording-guide/

Comment: The link may be useful, but the point of this site is to get the answers here, not to advertise your blog/social/media sites.  Consider alt least paraphrasing your guide and posting the relevant details here.

Comment: @Zoredache: you have a point, but don't assume he's just advertising his blog. That post is huge; reposting it here would be a lot of work. Paraphrasing is a good idea though.